# Copy content of one folder to another in linux

Tags: linux

I have a folder named **test** which has files and subdirectories in it. I want to copy the content of this **test** folder to another folder named **live** and here is what I did:

```
cp -pr /path/to/test/ /path/to/live/
```

But what I get is a folder test inside the live folder, but I don't want that. Then I tried this:

```
cp -pr /path/to/test/*.* /path/to/live/
```

But all I got was just files.

So, please tell me where am I doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're copying recursively, so no need for any wildcards.

Try

```
cp -pr /path/to/test/. /path/to/live/
```

Comment: wouldn't this make a dir test in dir live?

Comment: Sorry, add trailing slash and it wont.

Comment: this is exactly what I did and I got a folder test inside the folder live

Comment: You need to add a trialing period to the first path name. Fixed that for you. Or, use rsync: `rsync -a /path/to/test/ /path/to/live/`

Answer (score 0):

*.* implies files since you've specified an extension. You're using recursion (-r) so just use /* in place of /*.* and you should get folders.

Comment: ah, I figured it out when posting, but thanx for your reply, will mark it as correct.

Comment: I wish to note that the `cp` command itself, never 'sees' the asterisks, but they are expanded by the shell prior to `cp` being run. This means if there are 20 items in `/path/to/test/` then `cp` is run with its `-pr` switch, plus 21 filenames/paths. The last one listed is treated as the destination. This means that using `*.*` will also pickup folder names that contain an internal dot. If you want to also get hidden files and folders set the bash dotglob option `shopt -s dotglob`. You can test the effect of globbing using the echo command, e.g. `echo *` and `echo *.*`

Comment: INCORRECT - this answer will miss any .dotfiles present in the directory.

Comment: @MikeyB: thank you for the update, I have corrected my correct answer